# 'Tag in is protected' error in eigenvaules for large size Hamiltonian

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I am trying to compute the eigenvalues for any size Hamiltonian matrix. To do this, I first manually compute the first few cases for N=2,3. However, when I want to see what happens for N=4, I meet this error:

```
\[Sigma][1] = ( {
    {0, 1},
    {1, 0}
   } );
\[Sigma][2] = ( {
    {0, -i},
    {i, 0}
   } );
\[Sigma][3] = ( {
    {1, 0},
    {0, -1}
   } );
identity = ( {
    {1, 0},
    {0, 1}
   } );
KroneckerProduct[\[Sigma][1], \[Sigma][1]];
j/h = 1/2;
H = h*((-j/
      h*(KroneckerProduct[\[Sigma][1], \[Sigma][1], identity, 
         identity] + 
        KroneckerProduct[identity, \[Sigma][1], \[Sigma][1], 
         identity] + 
        KroneckerProduct[identity, 
         identity, \[Sigma][1], \[Sigma][
          1]])) + (KroneckerProduct[\[Sigma][3], identity, identity, 
       identity] + 
      KroneckerProduct[identity, \[Sigma][3], identity, identity] + 
      KroneckerProduct[identity, identity, \[Sigma][3], identity] + 
      KroneckerProduct[identity, identity, identity, \[Sigma][3]]))
```

and the error is

```
Set: "Tag Times in j/h is Protected".
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this? I think I didn't miss any semicolon.

Comment: With `j/h = 1/2;` You try to assign a value to the expression `j/h` whose `FullForm` is `Times[Power[h,-1],h]`. The `Head` of this expression is `Times` and you try to assign a `DownValue` to it although `Times` has the attribute `Protected` -- for a good reason by the way. So take this messages as a hint that you were trying to do something really wrong...

Comment: I propose to close this question for it is a frequently observed mistake. This is a general policy on this site. Please do not take it personally. Your contributions _are_ welcome here.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What policy has I violate?

Comment: Sorry that I did not phrase it better. You have not violated any policy. You did nothing wrong. What I meant is this: It is a general policy that users (like me) close questions that are not of general interest (e.g., because they are about a simple syntax error like your question). When I mentioned you were doing "something really wrong", I meant that the assignment `j/h = 1/2;` does not make any sense. If You like, you can use another symbol like in`joverh = 1/2` to store the value of `1/2`.